# Como fixar uma div no eixo Y usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

eu estou tentando deixar uma div fixa na VERTICAL, e que quando movimentar a barra de rolagem, o restante do conteúdo dessa mesma div parecesse normalmente, usei o position fixed, mas o restante do conteúdo não aparece. eu já tentei com CSS, mas não consegui e agora que estou conhecendo melhor javascript.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <style>
       *{margin:0; padding:0;}
       #fixar {position:fixed; background-color:#666; height:1000px; width:500px;}
       #conteudo {width:50000px; height:1000px; background-color:#CCC; margin-left:505px;}
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="fixar">
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
       <p>conteúdo fixo</p>
      <p>ESSE CONTEÚDO FICA "CORTADO"</p>
    </div>

   <div id="conteudo">
      <p>conteúdo normal</p>
      <p>conteúdo normal</p>
      <p>conteúdo normal</p>
      <p>conteúdo normal</p>
      <p>conteúdo normal</p>
      <p>conteúdo normal</p>
      <p>conteúdo normal</p>
      <p>conteúdo normal</p>
      <p>conteúdo normal</p>
      <p>conteúdo normal</p>
    </div>



   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Caren, podes colocar o código que tens e que tem o problema que descreveste _"o restante do conteúdo não aparece"_?

Comment: No html, a div "fixar" eu gostaria que ela ficasse fixa sem que o resto do conteúdo sumisse.

Comment: Clica em [edit] e junta o código para percebermos melhor o problema

Comment: A div "fixar" eu quero que ela fique fixa, e que o todo o conteúdo aparecesse, mas com position:fixed; o restante do conteúdo é "cortado"

Comment: Um simples `overflow-y: auto; height: 100%;` no CSS da sua div fixa não resolveria o problema?

Comment: O problema é que eu não quero que a div "fixar" crie barra de rolagem, a unica barra que eu quero é a normal do navegador, eu preciso que o conteúdo dessa div apareça normalmente, só que preciso dela sempre fixa, por isso acho que só com css não da pra fazer.

Comment: Se não quer a barra de scroll pode adicionar .className::-webkit-scrollbar{display:none;}. O conteudo é cortado no final da sua div, se quer que apareça todo o conteúdo terá de aumentar a height dessa div.